# React Native com PHP

Tags: php, api, react, react-native

Boa noite a todos!

Tenho um app desenvolvido em React Native e estou consumindo uma API feita em PHP, porém o arquivo dessa API está na minha máquina, não está em nenhum servidor. Quando eu subir meu app para a playstore, obrigatoriamente eu vou ter que subir os arquivos PHP para um servidor?

Comment: sim......................

Comment: Quanto a esse ponto seja profissional e não mão fechada, contrate uma empresa de hospedagem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SIM e NÃO.

SIM, pois é mais prático, já que a forma de conectividade será muito mais fácil, com você registrando um domínio, comprando uma hospedagem, e direcionando as chamadas do APP para esta estrutura.

NÂO, se você tiver a estrutura de rede da sua casa com a por 80 do seu modem ou roteador liberados na porta 80/443 ou similar (o que nem sempre acontece por conta da operadoras), daí você aponta o seu IP se ele for fixo, ou colocar um DNS, comprado ou grátis, isso exige pesquisas...

Eu recomendo o caminho do sim, por ser mais prático e na minha opinião, mais correto.

Boa sorte!